# Replace specific abbreviations of measurement units in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, data-cleaning, topic-modeling

I have a dataset (a text corpus) that I am working on for topic modeling. 
Within the dataset *units of measurement* or *currencies* are differently spelled or abbreviated. For example, 250m stand for 250 meters, 12cm for 12 centimeters, 10€ for 10 Euros. Since it is not relevant for the analysis whether someone writes about inches, centimeters, meters or miles I want to take these abbreviations and replace them all with one single word, for example the word "distanceunit".

Unfortunately, there is no uniform abbreviation used in the text corpus, as I am analyzing user generated content data. Thus, I am not sure how I can write a code that allows R to replace these units (measurement units or currencies) with one specified word ("distanceunit" for meters, inch, etc. and "currency" for all currencies).

I thought about using gsub to convert them. However, one would need to account for different writings and spacings, like "250m" vs. "250 m" vs. "250 m." vs. "250m."

Is there a way to write a gsub function that accounts for the different writing methods above once I have defined all units of measurements that I want to have replaced? Are there any R packages that might help with that issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t <- c("250m foo", "250 m foo", "250 m. foo", "250m. foo", "300 Apples", "1963 May")
```

I tried to find a restrictive regex to avoid fals-positives. Not sure how bad your results will be...

Suggested regex looks for the following pattern: wordboundary (`\\b`), one or more digits (`[0-9]+`), followed by a single optional space (`[ ]?`), one or more letter m and/or M (`[mM]+`)and a wordboundary followed by a single optional period (`\\b[.]?`).

The group with the numbers is then re-inserted in the replacement argument (the `\\1` in `"\\1 distanceunit"`)

```
gsub("(\\b[0-9]+)[ ]?[mM]+\\b[.]?", "\\1 distanceunit", t)
```

Returns:

```
> "250 distanceunit foo" "250 distanceunit foo" "250 distanceunit foo" "250 distanceunit foo" "300 Apples"           "1963 May"
```